# How to make appear sidebar on hover instead of click in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, hover

I am working on a shiny application and have used shinydashboard package for the UI part. I want to open the sidebar on hover instead of click on the button. I have tried data-trigger option but it is not working. Can anyone please help me in doing this?

A minimal example for the shiny dashboard application

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with JQuery:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(),
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML("$(function() { $('a.sidebar-toggle').mouseover(function(e) { $(this).click()})});")))
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. One more thing, Is it possible to left-align the hover button as well on mouse hover?