# Hide dropdown options on shinydashboard when click out

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to exit an option (`menuSubItem`) when I click outside of this field, but the option does not disappear when I click outside. I tried a solution with CSS, but it didn't work! My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard", titleWidth = 320)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = 320,
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(
      text = "A1"
    ),
    menuItem(
      text = "A2",
      menuSubItem(
        text = "AA1"
      ),
      menuSubItem(
        text = "AA2"
      ), 
      menuSubItem(
        text = "AA3"
      )
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody()

ui <- dashboardPage(header = header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to click outside of `A2` and have it (`A2`) close the dropdown menu when this click is done.

I tried insert this code in body:

```
body <- dashboardBody(

  HTML(
  "<script>

  $(function() {

    $(document).on('click', function() {
      $('.skin-blue .treeview-menu>li>a').slideUp();
    });
 
  });

  </script>"
  )

)
```

But don't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to expand/collapse the shiny dashboard sidebar on mouse hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169153/how-to-expand-collapse-the-shiny-dashboard-sidebar-on-mouse-hover)

Comment: @manro Unfortunately not. I need the submenus AA1, AA2 and AA3 (from A2) to disappear after clicking on any area of ​​the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can provide the `menuItem` with an `id` and remove the css class `menu-open`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard", titleWidth = 320)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 320,
                            sidebarMenu(
                              menuItem(text = "A1"),
                              menuItem(
                                text = "A2",
                                id = "A2ID",
                                menuSubItem(text = "AA1"),
                                menuSubItem(text = "AA2"),
                                menuSubItem(text = "AA3")
                              )
                            ))

body <- dashboardBody(tags$script(
  HTML(
    "$(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {
        $(document).on('click', function(evt) {
          if($(evt.target).closest('#sidebarItemExpanded > ul > li.treeview').length)
            return;
          var el = document.getElementById('A2ID');
          el.style.display = 'none';
          el.classList.remove('menu-open');
      });
    });"
  )
))

ui <- dashboardPage(header = header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Some related links:

[jQuery click anywhere in the page except on 1 div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661797/jquery-click-anywhere-in-the-page-except-on-1-div)

https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/347

Comment: Nice, it works. But, how do I click on "A1" and it also disappears, or any other link that is inside the application?

Comment: Please check my edit.